# Eclipse not recognizing slf4j or logback Logger class methods

Tags: eclipse, spring-mvc, slf4j, logback

I have recently been tasked to begin architecting a new Spring 3 MVC project (I am quite the noob in this regard). Having set up most of the POC project in Kepler, I have:

- a prototype webapp (HelloWorld style) that is deployable and
  working in (an external) Tomcat7.
- Logback configured and reporting to the console:

```
...
12:46:21.916 [http-apr-8080-exec-5] TRACE o.s.w.s.v.InternalResourceViewResolver - Cached view [home]
12:46:21.916 [http-apr-8080-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'home'; URL [/WEB-INF/view/home.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'sample'
12:46:21.916 [http-apr-8080-exec-5] TRACE o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView - Rendering view with name 'home' with model {name=lingxotika.org} and static attributes {}
12:46:21.916 [http-apr-8080-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView - Added model object 'name' of type [java.lang.String] to request in view with name 'home'
12:46:21.921 [http-apr-8080-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView - Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/view/home.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'home'
12:46:21.957 [http-apr-8080-exec-5] TRACE o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@1bb3db1b
12:46:21.960 [http-apr-8080-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
12:46:21.960 [http-apr-8080-exec-5] TRACE o.s.w.c.s.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Publishing event in WebApplicationContext for namespace 'sample-servlet': ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/codetutr/home/]; client=[127.0.0.1]; method=[GET]; servlet=[sample]; session=[0108E781644C1268FD92C11BD78888FB]; user=[null]; time=[87ms]; status=[OK]
```

- but when I go into my code into use the `Logger` class methods (I've tried both
  `org.slf4j.Logger` and `ch.qos.logback.classic` flavors), Eclipse
  does not recognize the methods in the Logger instance:

```
    package org.lingxotika.controller;

    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.Model;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

    @Controller
    public class SampleController {
        static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SampleController.class);

        log.info("Hit Controller...");    // Error is here

        @RequestMapping("home")
        public String loadHomePage(Model model) {
            model.addAttribute("name", "lingxotika.org");
            return "home";
        }
    }
```

The Eclipse Code Assist after typing `log.` shows the following options (sorry, can't post screenshots yet):

```
new - create new object
nls - non-externalized string marker
runnable - runnable
toarray - convert collection to array
```

To sum, I have seen examples [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/07/junit-logback-maven-with-spring-3.html) and [here](http://java-success.blogspot.com/2013/03/logging-in-java-with-logback-and-mdc.html) that suggest this isn't a limitation of Spring or my admitted lack of competency with it, but an Eclipse issue that I am overlooking. I avoided posting what could be irrelevant information, but am happy to supply any further code, logs, or config examples. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I should add that I have already performed the requisite `Project -> Clean`/`Refresh`, `Maven -> Update Project...`, restart Eclipse, restart my laptop, blow-away and re-import the project, and `mvn eclipse:clean`/`mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you dont have the slf4j api jar in your project.

Since it is working in tomcat, perhaps tomcat is using a "provided" jar, ie: one that is part of the tomcat application.

If you are using maven, you need to have the following dependency in you pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I believe I have all the needed dependencies (I am using Maven), as without any one of them, the binding to the handler fails somwhere and the resource is rendered unavailable to Tomcat. I am leaning heavily towards this being an IDE issue, such a build path misconfiguration or the like.

Comment: do you see the log.info("Hit Controller...") in the logs when run in tomcat?

Comment: No, as the project won't compile because `info` isn't a method in the Logger instance (although the compiler has no problem with the `static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SampleController.class);` line...).

Comment: did you try putting the log.info() inside the method instead of at class level?

Comment: Brilliant, of course that worked.:) Once again, a testament to the value of a second set of eyes. I will vote up your answer as soon as my rep is high enough. Thanks for the help.